# ctrl scroll to zoom terminal emulator using tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, xdotool

I am using the following tmux keybindings to zoom using the mouse wheels.

```
# Ctrl Scroll to Zoom
bind-key -T root C-WheelUpPane { 
       run-shell "xdotool key Ctrl+plus"
}

bind-key -T root C-WheelDownPane { 
       run-shell "xdotool key Ctrl+minus"
}

bind-key -T root C-MouseDown2Pane { 
       run-shell "xdotool key Ctrl+0"
}
```

However, I am having a little issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> situated on the left hand side. It works properly with the right hand side <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. However, the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is acting as if I am letting go of the control key. And instead of zooming, it is suddenly entering tmux copy-mode.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue does not occur in macbook.

At this moment it appears to be a bug in muffin WM.

The diagnosis details is in https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2345

The issue is reported in https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin/issues/569